# ListView scrolls automatically when number of rows are increasing but the parent layout overlaps it

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a customized listview which I've put it in a relative layout and there are some buttons  and labels around it which this layout is stored in table_layout.xml file and  in each row of the listview there are three textviews and one checkbox which these textboxes are going to be populated with the data extracted from the database in runtime and I wrote this layout in a separate xml file called cell.xml,but when I run the application the buttons and the textview in table_layout.xml overlap each other and also the listview. but the listview scrolls when the rows are being added to  it.I couldn't find the reason,I'll be glad if you suggest me a solution.

Here is table_layout.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/GOODNAME_CELL"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Order"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        />
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/GOODUNITPRICE_CELL"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Unit Price"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/GOODNAME_CELL"
        />
      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/QUANTITYCELL"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/GOODUNITPRICE_CELL"
        />



 <ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/GOODUNITPRICE_CELL"
     >
    </ListView>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/TotalPriceTextview"
     android:layout_width="600dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text=""
     android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:background="@drawable/back"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:textSize="20dp"
        />
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/DeleteSelectedGoodsButton"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:text="@string/DeleteSelectedGoods"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   />
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/ConfirmDelete"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:text="@string/ConfirmDeleteButton"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

     />
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/CancelButton"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:text="@string/CancelButton"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is cell.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

    >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/GOOD_NAME_CELL"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:paddingLeft="5dp"

        />
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/GOOD_UNITPRICE_CELL"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:paddingLeft="5dp"

        />
      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/QUANTITY_CELL"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

        />
        <CheckBox 
          android:layout_width="40dp"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:id="@+id/ChkOrder"
         android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:focusable="false"

          />  

    </LinearLayout>
```

And here is the screenshot:
[image]

Code.java:

```
package com.example.nfc;


import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import com.example.nfc.ExternalDbOpenHelper;

import android.R.integer;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PrepopSqliteDbActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "NFC.sqlite";
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Tbl_Goods";
    private static final String GOOD_ID = "Good_ID";
    private static final String CART_ID = "Cart_ID";
    private static final String GOOD_NAME = "Good_Name";
    private static final String GOOD_UNITPRICE = "Good_UnitPrice";
    private static final String QUANTITY = "Quantity";


     Cursor goodsCursor;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ListView listView;
     int checkedItemPosition;




    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> goods=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.table_layout);

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
        //--------------------------------------



        fillgoods();
        ShowTotalPrice() ;
        setUpList(); 




  //////Delete Button

       Button DeleteGoods=(Button)findViewById(R.id.DeleteSelectedGoodsButton);
       DeleteGoods.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                /** Getting the position of the currently selected item**/

                  DeleteCheckedItem(checkedItemPosition);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The selected order has been deleted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());

            }

        });

        ///Confirm Button
       Button btnConfirm=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ConfirmDelete);
       btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //ShowTotalPrice();

        }
    });
        ///Cancel Button
        Button btnCancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.CancelButton);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                finish();
            }
        });

//ListView OnItemClickListener


listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.ChkOrder);

            int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            for(int i=firstPosition;i<listView.getCount();i++){
            View v=listView.getChildAt(i);
            cbx = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.ChkOrder);
            if(cbx.isChecked()){

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                 "Checked position " + goods.get(i), 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 checkedItemPosition=i;


           }
        }

     }

});

    }


    private void setUpList() {

        setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, goods, R.layout.cells,
                new String[]{GOOD_NAME,GOOD_UNITPRICE,QUANTITY},
                new int[]{R.id.GOOD_NAME_CELL,R.id.GOOD_UNITPRICE_CELL,
                R.id.QUANTITY_CELL}));



        //---------------------------------layout------------------------------------



        listView = getListView();
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

///////////////////////
View footer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
  R.layout.footer, null);

listView.addFooterView(footer);
///////////////////////////////////////

            }
    private void DeleteCheckedItem(int chkPosition)
    {   
        String strName=goods.get(chkPosition).get(GOOD_NAME);
        String strPrice=goods.get(chkPosition).get(GOOD_UNITPRICE);
        String strQuantity=goods.get(chkPosition).get(QUANTITY);

        String whereClause = "GOOD_NAME = ? AND GOOD_UNITPRICE= ? AND QUANTITY= ?";
        String[] whereArgs = {strName,strPrice,strQuantity};

        database.delete(TABLE_NAME, whereClause, whereArgs);

        fillgoods();
    }




    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void fillgoods() {
        goods = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
         Cursor goodsCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,
                                             new String[] 
                                             {GOOD_ID,CART_ID,GOOD_NAME,GOOD_UNITPRICE,QUANTITY},
                                             null, null, null, null
                                             , GOOD_NAME);


        String[] goodsTable=new String[] 
                 {GOOD_NAME,GOOD_UNITPRICE,QUANTITY};
        goodsCursor.moveToFirst();
        String[] names=new String[1000];
        if(!goodsCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                 int i=0;

                 names[i] = goodsCursor.getString(2);
                 names[i+1]=goodsCursor.getString(3);
                 names[i+2]=goodsCursor.getString(4);


                 map=new HashMap<String, String>();

                 map.put(goodsTable[i],names[i]);
                 map.put(goodsTable[i+1], names[i+1]);
                 map.put(goodsTable[i+2], names[i+2]); 


                 goods.add(map);


            } while (goodsCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        goodsCursor.close();

    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //////////////Home And Back Button
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
       this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
      super.onAttachedToWindow();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)

           BackToMainIntent();

     else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
       {
         BackToMainIntent();
      }
       return false;
    }



    public void BackToMainIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           startActivity(intent);
      }
    }
```

Logcat:

```
02-16 11:26:51.171: E/AndroidRuntime(222): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nfc/com.example.nfc.PrepopSqliteDbActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at com.example.nfc.PrepopSqliteDbActivity.ShowTotalPrice(PrepopSqliteDbActivity.java:164)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at com.example.nfc.PrepopSqliteDbActivity.onCreate(PrepopSqliteDbActivity.java:79)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
02-16 11:26:51.182: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  ... 11 more
02-16 11:26:51.192: I/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 222 SIG: 3
02-16 11:26:51.192: I/dalvikvm(222): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-16 11:26:51.202: E/dalvikvm(222): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
02-16 11:26:51.373: I/ARMAssembler(51): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x4e2f38:0x4e2ff4] in 383010 ns
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a screenshot from the ui on the device?

Comment: same question as endian...

Comment: @ShadiS do u want the tree buttons at the botton to be scrolled with the listview's items or not ?

Comment: Yes of course!I want the buttons and also `TotalPriceTextview` which is not in the photo to be scrolled!

Comment: @ShadiS i give you an answer, if you want the buttons to be scrolled with the listview's items you have to use the `second option` in my answer, If you want to give you a full working example please give you you adapter , activity code

Comment: @ShadiS would you tell me if your problem has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is two solutions:

**First** you can put the tree buttons with textview in a linearlayout and put this linearlayout at the botton of the xml layout

#### In this case the buttons won't scroll with the items

```
<Linearlayout layout_width= "fill_parent"
layout_hight = "warp_conetent"
orentation = "horizantally"
alighparentbotton = "true"
>
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/TotalPriceTextview"
     android:layout_width="600dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text=""
     android:background="@drawable/back"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:textSize="20dp"
        />
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/DeleteSelectedGoodsButton"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:text="@string/DeleteSelectedGoods"
   />
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/ConfirmDelete"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:text="@string/ConfirmDeleteButton"

     />
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/CancelButton"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:text="@string/CancelButton"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

     />
</linearlayout>
```

**Second** you can use put these three buttons and textview in a footer and add this footer to the listview **In this case the footer will scroll with the items**

```
  View footer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                    R.layout.footer, null);

yourListView.addFooterView(footer);
```

#### footer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    >
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/TotalPriceTextview"
     android:layout_width="600dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text=""
     android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:background="@drawable/back"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:textSize="20dp"
        />
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/DeleteSelectedGoodsButton"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:text="@string/DeleteSelectedGoods"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   />
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/ConfirmDelete"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:text="@string/ConfirmDeleteButton"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

     />
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/CancelButton"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:text="@string/CancelButton"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### after your edit

```
package com.stackoverflow.questions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import android.R.integer;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StackActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "NFC.sqlite";
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Tbl_Goods";
    private static final String GOOD_ID = "Good_ID";
    private static final String CART_ID = "Cart_ID";
    private static final String GOOD_NAME = "Good_Name";
    private static final String GOOD_UNITPRICE = "Good_UnitPrice";
    private static final String QUANTITY = "Quantity";

    Cursor goodsCursor;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ListView listViewsssss;
    int checkedItemPosition;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> goods = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.table_layout);
        // fillgoods();
        setUpList();

    }

    private void setUpList() {

        listViewsssss = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        View footer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.footer, null);

        listViewsssss.addFooterView(footer);

        listViewsssss.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, goods, R.layout.cell,
                new String[] { GOOD_NAME, GOOD_UNITPRICE, QUANTITY },
                new int[] { R.id.GOOD_NAME_CELL, R.id.GOOD_UNITPRICE_CELL,
                        R.id.QUANTITY_CELL }));

        // ---------------------------------layout------------------------------------

        listViewsssss.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        // /////////////////////

        // /////////////////////////////////////

    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)

            BackToMainIntent();

        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            BackToMainIntent();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void BackToMainIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StackActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

[image]

#### I changed the footer to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TotalPriceTextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asdf"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/DeleteSelectedGoodsButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="asdf" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ConfirmDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="sdaf" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CancelButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="asdf" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have added the footer and deleted the views which are in the footer from my table lay out and I changed my code like the code which H have added to my question,please review my question.Thanks for your concern

Comment: I get an exception in runtime!what is my mistake here?

Comment: I have put the logcat for you in my question

Comment: what is the exception that u have got ?

Comment: Force close Nullpointer at runtime!did I put the ` View footer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                    R.layout.footer, null);

yourListView.addFooterView(footer);
`   in the right place?

Comment: you have to use your listview name not `youListView` , also i am still checking

Comment: I know,I've changed the name to my own listView

Comment: @ShadiS check it please, i extend activity not listactivity, because i don't have the databasae, if you want give me arrays of strings that contains the data, put it in you `simpleadapter` and give it to me to test it for you, it will work

Comment: Thanks,bit I still get the same exception

Comment: i also got the exception , check my java code, i just use your setList function , that means the exception from your database, remember i extent activity not listactivity, i supposed that you start a new thread about ur database function , the exception is there not in the listview, because it works with me as i showed you a print screen

Comment: also you can search for adding footer to listactivity not to activity, i am sure that it is 100% your answer

Comment: Thanks for you help!I'm going to check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot It is solved bu using a footer but one of my buttons which is for deleting the checked Items in the listview gives runtime exception!can you help me please?